# Html string with <div> tag and style in android textview and webview not working

Tags: android, html, string, webview, textview

I'm trying to show display an html string in a textview and in a webview, but it doesnt't work; i tryed to use the Html.fromhtml method and and the loaddata method but without any success; can anyone here help with that; i receive the html string by a webservice and this is the kind of html string i have to deal with :

```
    <br /> 
    <div style="float:left; width:auto;" >
            <p style="text-align:center;" ><b><font color="red" >Gratuit</font></b></p><br /> 
   </div> <!-- centre description + commentaire --> 
   <div style="float:left;" > 
        <b>MAJ :</b> Le deal est désormais fonctionnel <img src="http://www.dealabs.com/images/smiley/img-clindoeil.png" width="16" height="16" alt=";)" title=";)" class="bbcode_smiley" />.<br /> <br /> Ashampoo Movie Studio 2013 giveaway!<br /> <br /> 
        <i>Ashampoo Movie Studio inclut tout ce dont vous avez besoin pour éditer et produire vos films maison du début à la fin et en vous aidant, étape par étape.<br /> 
        - Coupez, donnez à vos vidéos la bonne taille et convertissez-les<br /> - Ajoutez de la musique de fond<br /> 
        - Appliquez des effets de transition et de superpositions de texte<br />
        - Exportez vers un fichier ou gravez sur disque</i><br /> 
        Pour plus d'informations sur le logiciel: 
    <a href="http://www.dealabs.com/url/?e=d0LDKXKUsr0ZM7dF3ioVPm0CYs%2Ftv3RVHUsT6JDUsmAJuOEbkpH9M9LhA77MnY%2FzuvPalzQ0v92xrESZPsw%2FLpulAtqIDEE8IWtyOR%2Fv6AthXUCI8ibuUg%3D%3D" style="color:#008EAB;" target="_blank" >https://www.ash[...]vie-Studio</a><br /> <br /> Pour telecharger le logiciel, allez sur le site de downloadmix.de:<br /> 
    <a href="http://www.dealabs.com/url/?e=5CUJf3iMXUuBEnlS6dQfgouiXJJcgK0Pf0OhHrtr3mHGAbZ5Vrc7jYOpM7I27Q5PYIdF%2FZoGdSJf0MVmG15nJGPFWcPUHzbX2hags7h2YC0%3D" style="color:#008EAB;" target="_blank" >http://dl01.dow[...]_13875.exe</a><br /> 
    Apparemment, c'est la version 1.0.0 et la dernière est la 1.0.3. La licence semble être pour la version 1.0.0 uniquement.<br /> <br /> Pour avoir une clé gratuite: 
    <a href="http://www.dealabs.com/url/?e=ccHf4xTB73y4V6CvbSILZPPqXAzsw7EouqI4oXaLBpGna%2FgoxsxPY85DIMQDPgorahhJn4KUf040lojrQ9z9LjhckEymP1hdqBMsHNTDCxQ%2FsFXvBr0yu8MXZcFOjgfXM3%2Fl73f6Ndu0QUVpv7xRxQ%3D%3D" style="color:#008EAB;" target="_blank" >http://www.asha[...]azyrjbuo5l</a>
    <br /> 1- mettez une adresse email<br /> 
    2- activez le lien dans l'email<br /> 
    3- remplissez les informations demandées (non obligatoire)<br /> 
    4- recuperez la cle<br /> <br /> J'ai pu recuperer une cle sans soucis, <del>pas encore pu l'essayer (ca telecharge...)</del> et enregistré le logiciel sans soucis!<br /> <br /> Je ne sais pas quand cela termine...

</div>
```

Thanks u all.

Comment: [Please edit your code, format it and make it readable](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18057570/edit).

Comment: Why don't you put above html directly in a `WebView`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, not all html tags are supported. Mark Murphy (aka CommonsGuy) posted a list of [available tags](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) and properties that you can rely on. I am not sure how much up-to-date that list is.

Answer (score 0):

Surround that html code with

```
<html> ... </html>
```

And then use it by:

```
webView.loadData(totalHtmlString,"text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```